# How to fetch response body using fetch in case of HTTP error 422?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, http, error-handling, fetch-api

I have an API on backend which sends status `201` in case of a successful call and if there's
any error with the submitted data it sends status `422` (Unprocessable Entity) with a json response like below:

```
{
  "error": "Some error text here explaining the error"
}
```

Additionally it sends `404` in case API fails to work on back end for some reason.

On the front-end I'm using the below code to fetch the response and perform a success or error callback based on response status code:

```js
fetch("api_url_here", {
    method: 'some_method_here', 
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      'X-CSRF-Token': "some_token_here"
    }
    })
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(function json(response) {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(resp){
    successCallback(resp)
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    errorCallback(error);
  });
  
//status function used above
checkStatus = (response) => {
  if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
    return Promise.resolve(response)
  } else {
    return Promise.reject(new Error(response))
  }
}
```

The `successCallback` function is able to receive the response in proper JSON format in case of status code `201` but when I try to fetch the error response in `errorCallback` (`status: 422`) it shows something like this (logging the response in console):

```
Error: [object Response]
    at status (grocery-market.js:447)
```

When I try to `console.log` the error response before wrapping it in `new Error()` like this,

```
  checkStatus = (response) => {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
      return Promise.resolve(response)
    } else {
      console.log(response.json()) //logging the response beforehand
      return Promise.reject(new Error(response.statusText))
    }
  }
```

I get the below promise in console (the `[[PromiseValue]]` property actually contains the error text that i require)

[image]

Can someone please explain why this is happening only in error case, even though I'm calling `response.json()` in both error and success case?

How can I fix this in a clean manner?

**EDIT:**
I found that if I create another `json()` promise on the error response I am able to get the correct error :

```js
fetch("api_url_here", {
    method: 'some_method_here', 
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      'X-CSRF-Token': "some_token_here"
    }
    })
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(function json(response) {
    return response.json()
  })
  .then(function(resp){
    successCallback(resp)
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    error.json().then((error) => { //changed here
        errorCallback(error)
      });
  });
```

But why do I have to call another `.json()` on the response in error case?

Comment: Response.json() is async so you might want to make checkStatus async and await the response

Comment: @SørenEriksen yeah i understood that but fetching response in checkStatus in probably not the cleanest way to do this. That i did just to check what was happening beforehand.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Short answer**

Because your assumption that you parse the response content twice is incorrect. In the original snippet, the `then` after the `then(checkStatus)` is skipped when the error condition is met.

**Long answer**

In general, well-structured [promise chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining) consists of a:

1. Promise to be *fulfilled* or *rejected* sometime in the future
2. `then` handler that is run only *upon fulfillment* of the Promise
3. `catch` handler that is run only *upon rejection* of the Promise
4. `finally` (optional) that is run when a Promise is *settled* (in either 2 or 3)

Each of the handlers in 2 and 3 *return a Promise* to enable chaining.

Next, `fetch` method of the Fetch API [rejects only on network failures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch), so the first `then` method is called regardless of the `status` code of the response. Your first handler, the [`onFulfilled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) callback returns either a fulfilled or rejected Promise.

If fulfilled, it passes control to the next `then` method call in the chain, where you extract JSON by calling `json` method on the response, which is then passed as Promise value to the last `then` method to be used in the `successCallback`.

If rejected, the control is passed to the `catch` method call, which receives the Promise with the value set to `new Error(response)` that you then promptly pass to `errorCallback`. Therefore, the latter receives an instance of `Error`, whose value is an instance of [`Response`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response) from Fetch API.

That is exactly what you see logged: `Error: [object Response]`, a result of calling `toString` method on an instance of `Error`. The first part is the constructor name, and the second is a string tag of the contents (of the form [type Constructor]).

**What to do?**

Since your API returns JSON response for every possible use case (`201`, `404`, `422`), pass the parsed response to both fulfilled and rejected promise. Also, note that you accidentally declared `checkStatus` on the global scope by omitting a `var`, `const`, or `let` keyword:

```js
//mock Response object
const res = {
  status: 200,
  body: "mock",
  async json() {
    const {
      body
    } = this;
    return body;
  }
};

const checkStatus = async (response) => {

  const parsed = await response.json();

  const {
    status
  } = response;

  if (status >= 200 && status < 300) {
    return parsed;
  }

  return Promise.reject(new Error(parsed));
};

const test = () => {

  return checkStatus(res)
    .then(console.log)
    .catch((err) => console.warn(err.message))
    .finally(() => {
      if (res.status === 200) {
        res.status = 422;
        return test();
      }
    });

};

test();
```

---

Additionally, since you already use ES6 features (judging by the presence of arrow functions), why not go all the way and use the syntactic sugar [`async`/`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) provides:

```
(() => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch("api_url_here", {
      method: 'some_method_here',
      credentials: "same-origin",
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        'X-CSRF-Token': "some_token_here"
      }
    });

    const parsed = await response.json(); //json method returns a Promise!

    const {
      status
    } = response;

    if (status === 201) {
      return successCallback(parsed);
    }

    throw new Error(parsed);

  } catch (error) {
    return errorCallback(error);
  }
})();
```

---

Note that when you are passing the `parsed` JSON content to the `Error()` constructor, an abstract `ToString` operation is called (see [step 3a](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-error-constructor) of the ECMA spec).

If the message is an object, unless the original object has a [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString#:%7E:text=Description,every%20object%20descended%20from%20Object%20.) method, you will get a string tag, i.e. `[object Object]`, resulting in the content of the object being inaccessible to the error handler:

```js
(() => {

  const obj = { msg : "bang bang" };
  
  const err = new Error(obj);
  
  //will log [object Object]
  console.log(err.message);
  
  obj.toString = function () { return this.msg; };
  
  const errWithToString = new Error(obj);

  //will log "bang bang"
  console.log(errWithToString.message);

})();
```

Contrary, if you `reject` a Promise with the object passed as an argument, the rejected Promise's `[[PromiseValue]]` will be the object itself.

Comment: In the checkStatus function that you have defined, you wrote `const parsed = response.json();`. Wouldn't it require an `await` before this statement and `async` before checkStatus function itself. Otherwise `return Promise.resolve(parsed)` in the IF statement would run before the `response.json()` is resolved.

Comment: Did I miss it? Oh, of course, it has to be with `await`, my bad. The lesson is - never use original snippets as frameworks :) I even mentioned "json method returns a Promise!" in the main snippet...

Comment: Also, this code in my snippet was causing issue `return Promise.reject(new Error(parsed));` .... wrapping the parsed response in `new Error` caused it to lose the json message for some reason ... just used `return Promise.reject(parsed);` and it's working fine now

Comment: @V_S_X - that's fairly easy to explain: I assumed that your API on error returns a string (which is a valid JSON) containing an error message. By spec, `Error` constructor accepts a `message`. When you invoke it, an abstract `ToString` operation is called on a message, and if it is an object, the result is string tag `[object Object]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's because in case of an error then handlers are skipped and the catch handler is executed, `checkStatus` returns a rejected promise and the remaining `then` chain is bypassed.

This is how I'd refactor your code.

```
checkStatus = async (response) => {
    if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) 
      return await response.json()

    throw await response.json()
  }
}


fetch("api_url_here", {
    method: 'some_method_here', 
    credentials: "same-origin",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
      'X-CSRF-Token': "some_token_here"
    }
    })
  .then(checkStatus)
  .then(successCallback)
  .catch(errorCallback);
```

P.S. this code can be made a bit better to look at visually by using `async/await`

Comment: `in case of an error then handlers are skipped and the catch handler is executed` .... by error do you mean `Promise.reject` or wrapping the response in `new Error`?

Comment: @V_S_X - I am pretty sure they meant promise rejection (you are correct in pointing out the potential confusion, though, as promise rejection and error being thrown are not the same things).

Comment: @V_S_X based on my observation, both.